# Yield return in AssetBundle.CreateFromMemory

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

As documentation says `IEnumerator` methods are executed like thread, but I'm confused why

```
AssetBundleCreateRequest assetBundleCreateRequest = AssetBundle.CreateFromMemory(ByteArray);
yield return assetBundleCreateRequest;
```

freezes my game for 2 seconds. Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 0):

Well it freezes for 2 seconds because that is what you are actually requesting with your *yield return assetBundleCreateRequest*

> Asynchronous operation coroutine.
>
> You can yield until asynchronous operation continues, or manually check whether it's done (isDone) or progress (progress). [AsyncOperation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation.html)

So right now you are requesting your coroutine to wait till your assetbundlecreaterequest is done.

For manually checking wheter the function is done, without having to freeze your application would be using the [isdone](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-isDone.html) or [progress](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-progress.html) command instead

If you need further clarification feel free to comment.

**Edit**

Sample of using isdone

```
AssetBundleCreateRequest acr = AssetBundle.CreateFromMemory(decryptedData);
while (!acr.isDone)
{
    yield;
}
AssetBundle bundle = acr.assetBundle;
```

Comment: I try this code, but now my game is freeze continuously: AssetBundleCreateRequest assetBundleCreateRequest  = AssetBundle.CreateFromMemory(ByteArray);
while(assetBundleCreateRequest.isDone != true);

Comment: @raert that is because you are using the isdone check incorrectly, see my edit for more information

Comment: As I use C# syntax  change yield; with  yield return null; but have same result, game is still freeze for a while;